# AJAX Control Toolkit TabContainer Throws Specified Argument Out of Range of Valid Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are using the Ajax Control Toolkit and have placed an UpdatePanel in a page.  The page layout is controlled by a master page.  The UpdatePanel contains numerous server side controls.  The code snippet to initiate the UpdatetePanel is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
    </Triggers>
```

Inside the UpdatePanel, there resides a TabContainer with numerous server side controls.  The code-behind references it as:

```
        TabPanel TabPanel3 = new TabPanel();
    TabPanel3.HeaderText = "Manually Enter Allergy";
    TabContainer1.Controls.Add(TabPanel3);
    for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
    {
        //CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
        //cb1.ID = "cbOther" + k;
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txtAOther" + k;
        txt.CssClass = "finput";
        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br/>" + k + ".&nbsp;";
        //TabPanel3.Controls.Add(cb1);
        TabPanel3.Controls.Add(lt);
        TabPanel3.Controls.Add(txt);

    }
```

The TabContainer is setup as follows:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
</asp:TabContainer>
```

When I run this page locally, I receive the following error:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
it originated in the code. 


Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of t
the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified 
using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value]
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer.set_ActiveTabIndex(Int32 value) +255
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer.OnInit(EventArgs e) +121
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +605
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean   
includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2238
```

I'm having difficulty understanding why the error is being thrown.  Initial searches don't yield definitive course of action.  Can anyone provide some guidance as to what could be done to remedy the error?

Comment: The error refers to setting the ActiveTabIndex.  Are you setting it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that in the ASPX you have no TabPanels.  That is why you are getting that error, because index 0 is not valid until you populate the tabs in PageLoad.

Get rid of the ActiveTabIndex=0 in your markup, and then after you have added your tabs programmatically, call it there:

`TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex=0;`